# Why does iptables block this curl even though the port is ACCEPTed?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

Here is a simple script to reset my iptables

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -I INPUT  -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

After this if I

```
curl another-machine:8000/filename
```

the connection hangs, it seems as though DROP and not ACCEPT is happening. If I

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

then the above `curl` command works.

But port `8000` is clearly set to `ACCEPT` even when `DROP` is the policy.

[image]

So why isn't the connection getting through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *remote* port and *destination* port are not the same thing. If an outgoing packet had 8000 as its destination port, then an incoming reply will have it as the *source* port (i.e. mirrored):

```
                local                   remote

 src 192.168.1.71:36932  --OUTPUT-->  151.101.1.69:8000 dest  TCP [SYN]

dest 192.168.1.71:36932  <--INPUT---  151.101.1.69:8000 src   TCP [SYN, ack]
```

In other words, only `-A INPUT -p tcp --sport 8000` will match it.

The more usual way of handling this is with a *stateful* firewall:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thanks. Regarding stateful firewalls, isn't the point of a firewall to drop/block connections *before* they become established? Otherwise how does established-ness of the state indicate that the connection meets the policy?

Comment: @spraff "*Regarding stateful firewalls, isn't the point of a firewall to drop/block connections before they become established?*" Yes, therefore we never want to block anything related to an established connection. "*Otherwise how does established-ness of the state indicate that the connection meets the policy?*" Since we don't establish connections that violate policy, if a connection is established, it complies with the policy.

Comment: There must be something very basic which I'm not getting here. My rules as they stand don't need an ESTABLISHED rule, so why would I add it? It seems redundant. And how does the connection become established if it wasn't already accepted? This seems tautological at best. You seem to have left out some mysterious *other* process which applies the policy. But if some other process exists, why do we need iptables at all?

Comment: @spraff: Because it's _part of_ iptables. The state is tracked by the _conntrack_ module. The outgoing TCP SYN still needs a port-based rule, but before it's sent, conntrack remembers its parameters (separately from the TCP stack). When a corresponding SYN+ACK is received, conntrack sees that its parameters match an earlier SYN and applies the 'ESTABLISHED' label to it, thus you can match it either by port _or_ by conntrack state. (Again, that's separate from actual TCP states. Conntrack applies equally to TCP connections and UDP streams.)

Comment: @spraff: The main difference between accepting input by port vs by state is that the latter won't accept bogus packets which _do not_ belong to the same connection. For example, someone could very easily try to establish a new connection to your port 22 by simply forcing their client to use 8000 as their source port. A stateless `-A INPUT --sport 8000 -j ACCEPT` would allow that, but a stateful rule would correctly block it.

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't answer the actual question. I'll rephrase. How do we prevent a connection from attaining an ESTABLISHED state if filtering happens based on whether it is established or not?